# React Conditional Rendering and Next.js Hydration Errors

Tags: next.js

In normal React, if you have data which may or may not exist at render time, you use conditional logic to return `null`.  For instance, if you have a `useCurrentUser` hook that retrieves the user from `localstorage`, and potentially returns `null`, you might write:

```
function SomePage() {
   const user = useCurrentUser();

   if (!user) return null;

   return <ActualPage/>;
}
```

However, when I try to do that pattern in Next.js, I get a hydration error.

Presumably it's because on the server `user` is null, but on the client (which has `localstorage`) there is a user, so the two conflict.

However, I can't figure out how to solve the problem.  The server will never have a user, and I need to handle that possibility with:

```
   if (!user) return null;
```

But, if I include that conditional logic, I get a hydration error.  Is there some pattern I can use to solve "data may/may not be there" rendering in Next, without creating hydration errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is an issue specific to local storage, and it can be solved by created a `useIsFirstRender` hook:

```
const useIsFirstRender = () => {
  const [isFirstRender, setIsFirstRender] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsFirstRender(false);
  }, []);
  return isFirstRender;
};
```

Once you have that hook, you can use it in your component like so:

```
function SomePage() {
   const user = useCurrentUser();
   const isFirstRender = useIsFirstRender();

   if (isFirstRender || !user) return null;

   return <ActualPage/>;
}
```

The hook (and it's `useEffect`) ensure we're not rendering on the server, solving the hydration error.

Comment: This shouldn't be called "`isMounted`", the component is already mounted when it's rendered. Really all it does is causing an artificial re-rendering. I'd call it `isFirstRender`

Comment: Good point: I edited the answer to have a more accurate hook name.